# Show Method for Dynamic Frame in AWS glue returns empty field

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue-spark

When I try to use the dyF.show() it returns an empty field, even though I checked the schema and count() and I know the table is populated. I transformed it into a spark dataframe and the show() method works fine.

I know that this has happened to others as well, is it a bug? Or it has to do with the file I am reading?

```
dyF.show()
```

but when I try it with a normal df:

```
df.show()
----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------------+----------------+
|YEAR|CARRIER|     CARRIER_NAME|MANUFACTURE_YEAR|UNIQUE_CARRIER_NAME|SERIAL_NUMBER|TAIL_NUMBER|AIRCRAFT_STATUS|OPERATING_STATUS|NUMBER_OF_SEATS|MANUFACTURER|  MODEL|CAPACITY_IN_POUNDS|ACQUISITION_DATE|
+----+-------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+----------------+---------------+------------+-------+------------------+----------------+
|2006|     16|PSA Airlines Inc.|            2003|  PSA Airlines Inc.|         7858|     N202PS|              B|               Y|             50|    CANADAIR|CRJ-2/4|             47000|      2003-10-28|
|2006|     16|PSA Airlines Inc.|            2003|  PSA Airlines Inc.|         7860|     N206PS|              B|               Y|             50|    CANADAIR|CRJ-2/4|             47000|      2003-10-30|
|2006|     16|PSA Airlines Inc.|            2003|  PSA Airlines Inc.|         7873|     N207PS|              B|               Y|             50|    CANADAIR|CRJ-2/4|             47000|      2003-11-26|
|2006|     16|PSA Airlines Inc.|            2003|  PSA Airlines Inc.|         7874|     N209PS|              B|               Y|             50|    CANADAIR|CRJ-2/4|             47000|      2003-12-04|
|2006|     16|PSA Airlines Inc.|            2003|  PSA Airlines Inc.|         7879|     N213PS|              B|               Y|             50|    CANADAIR|CRJ-2/4|             47000|      2003-12-16|
|2006|     16|PSA Airlines Inc.|            2003|  PSA Airlines Inc.|         7880|     N215PS|  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the option job bookmarks in job details. Change it to **disable**. For more information on job bookmark please refer link
[Job Bookmarks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html).
It will show data in the dataframe. Also show the data using the below syntax:
`dyf.toDF().show()`